# Bash script, checks its name, if it does not match with "script_name".sh, concatenates .sh to it's name and saves

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I came up with something like

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_NAME="$0"
EXTENSION=".sh"
FILE_NAME_MOD="$FILE_NAME$EXTENSION"

if [[ "$0" != "FILE_NAME_MOD" ]]; then
  cp "$0" | sed 's/\([^.sh]\)$/\1.sh/g' $0
fi
```

Obviously something wrong, Please help with the idea of it.

Comment: `if [[ $FILENAME != $FILE_NAME_MOD ]]; then echo mv -v "$FILENAME" "$FILENAME$EXTENSION"; fi`  remove the `echo` if you're ok with the result and `mv` can do it's job.

Comment: @Jetchisel Wouldn't that condition always be true? "foo.sh" != "foo.sh.sh"

Comment: Right, `if [[ $FILENAME != *.sh ]]; then echo mv -v "$FILENAME" "$FILENAME$EXTENSION"; fi` might do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `case` statement:

```
FILE_NAME=$0
EXTENSION='.sh'
FILE_NAME_MOD="$FILE_NAME$EXTENSION"

case "$FILE_NAME" in
    *"$EXTENSION") ;;
    * ) mv -i "$FILE_NAME" "$FILE_NAME_MOD" &&
        printf '%s\n' "file has been renamed to '$FILE_NAME_MOD'" ;;
esac
```

- In case `FILE_NAME` doesn't already end in `EXTENSION`, rename to `FILE_NAME_MOD`

Comment: Thank you, excuse my naive question, but the new file does not appear in directory.

Comment: @WojciechMierzejewski Try the updated the answer – the 'echo' command is changed to 'mv'

Comment: Thanks, how about using my SED structure in orginal version?